# unsupervised clustering followed by modeling each cluster to create a mixed model

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I am curious if this is an advisable approach. I am not applying this approach and am only interested in the theory of it.

let's say you have some set of features X and target Y.
X can account for some variance in Y but how they may related may vary depending on the 'type' of X (some hidden category, e.g. hospital ID, or factory ID etc.).

pulling from the idea of mixture of experts in ML or mixed models in general, would it be reasonable to first cluster X (unsupervised) then fit a model to each cluster. Assume we have plenty of data in each cluster.

essentially you would stack your unsupervised clustering algo on top where it acts as a meta filter, passing each sample to a downstream model.

1. Are there better ways to find unknown 'types' of X?
2. does this idea have a name/ related terminology?
3. are there precautions you must take if you implement this?

I also thought of how you could even cluster each sample but then assign a similarity index for each sample, for each cluster (distance or something similar). then you could use those to create a weighted output for each model. that way you are not creating a hard line for each category.

i found this [related question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/69592/clustering-a-dataset-and-creating-a-model-per-each-cluster) but there were no answers or activity